# How do I get a scheduled AWS lambda to edit file

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-lambda, storage, file-management

I am creating a flash briefing skill for personal use, I need to create a lambda function that overwrites the file that the flash briefing reads as source.

I am trying to find a host for this, first from the amazon storage services, but so far I have been unable to find a good storage service to do this.

Would it be possible with the amazon storage gateway? I have sftp net drive, so I could set that up as a connection if it's needed for it.

Comment: Why would S3 not be a good storage solution for this?

Comment: Would I be able to overwrite the file stored in S3 through a scheduled lambda code? S3 was in fact the first possible solution I looked at, but I was unable to find a way to overwrite from lambda

Comment: (Added the comment as an answer mistakenly and moving it to comment) You want to store and edit files? How frequent you edit files? What are the sizes?

Answer "It's just 1 file, an HTML file with only a few lines in it, no style elements, nothing special in it. It would need to be stored somewhere that can be accessed by the flash briefing skill so that it can be the source. It would need to be edited every hour or so, I was thinking that I could make an aws lambda scheduled event to do that"

Comment: @Z.Black why would you not be able to overwrite a file on S3 using a Lambda function? What did you see that led you to believe you couldn't overwrite a file on S3? Whenever you push a file to S3, if one already exists with the same key then it gets overwritten.

Comment: @MarkB - File overwrites are eventually consistent on S3; depending on the use case this may not be a great fit.

Comment: @ChrisPollard true, but that's different than "unable to overwrite a file on S3 from Lambda"

Comment: @ZBlack *overwriting* a file (object) in S3 from Lambda is exactly the same as *creating* a file (object) in S3 from Lambda.  The operation is the same, it doesn't matter whether the file is already there or not.